# Links to other SE sites should open natively

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

I was reading a comment in Workplace.SE that had a link to CognitiveScience.SE. I tapped the link and it opened in an in-app browser instead of behaving like any other SE site I pick from my list of favorites.

For example, see Lilienthal's comment on this question: [How do you kill imposter syndrome?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56698/how-do-you-kill-imposter-syndrome)

Comment: Can you share an example question?  This generally should work.

Comment: See Lilienthal's comment on this question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56698/how-do-you-kill-imposter-syndrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be improved in the next build.

Previously the app supported links like:

- [Links to other SE sites should open natively](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268612/links-to-other-se-sites-should-open-natively) (Yikes, this link was loading in the answer itself )
- [Links to other SE sites should open natively](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268612/links-to-other-se-sites-should-open-natively#comment871299_268612) (Comment)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/308415/pedro
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app+feature-request
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=[ios-app]+natively

This is being expanded to include:

- http://meta.stackexchange.com
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/users

In addition, tagged question links https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app+feature-request will lead to the new and improved tagged question UI.